# Book about a killer planet where only plastic weapons can be used

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, weapon, space-exploration

I'm looking for a book I read as a kid in high school. All I remember of it is:

2 characters (possibly male and female) travel to a "killer" planet where no metal can be present so take only plastic equipment including knifes and plastic bow and arrows. The planet had previously been landed on and either the planet itself, or a life-form that I remember being described as some sort of tower, can detect the presence of and control metal.

All members of the previous expedition had been killed as the planet/life-form assumed control of their equipment and used it against them.

The novel ends with one of the characters climbing the tower to kill whatever it is that controls metal.

Apologies for the lack of details, that's all I remember of the book but I'd love to read it again as I have good memories of it!

Comment: When did you read it (we don't know when you were in high school)? If you know, was it new at the time? Was it more of a children's book, young adult, adult?

Answer (score 11):

I'm 90% sure the book you're thinking of is ["Killer Planet" by Bob Shaw.](http://www.shadowdevil.com/jp/?p=183) It features Jan and Petra, male and female, making a journey to Verdia, the eponymous "Killer Planet" where "[many] people had gone to the planet never to return, including the brother of Jan Hazard" and "they discover the shattered and seared ships and equipment" from those who had voyaged there before.

As regards the metal, "[the] ship .... is made out of hard plastics rather than metal due to the nature of Verdia, which attacks metal."

Comment: Can you flesh this out a bit?  What elements of *Killer Planet* match the question's description?

Comment: ^All of them as far as I can tell. I read this book in school too, so my memory of the exact plot is fuzzy (it's been a few decades!) but a quick google seems to bare things out. [link](http://www.shadowdevil.com/jp/?p=183)

Comment: Kris, if you can edit that in, it'd be great.